# M.2 Daughter card interface

Tags: pcie, sata

I am planning to use M.2 daughter card in a design. I know that M.2 form factor support various type of cards like LTE, Wifi, BT, SSD etc. My doubt is that what is the host side interface for these cards.

If I plan to use a SATA M.2 SSD, what interface will it use to connect to my processor? Will it be SATA? Can anyone share standard pin out of M.2 connector?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2 actually answers all of this

Comment: There is a lot more than this if you just google it & believe me its confusing.

Comment: [This document](https://pcisig.com/sites/default/files/specification_documents/4_SMBus_interface_for_SSD_Socket_2_and_Socket_3.pdf#page=5) linked in the Wikipedia article seems to share quite a few pin-outs. If you have a SATA SSD, the interface will be SATA, otherwise it would be a PCIe SSD.